# Using Zapier to update Asana Task Custom Field Values

Tags: asana, zapier

I'm attempting to use `Zapier` to update an `Asana` task's custom field (labelled `Time Tracked Toggl`) to reflect the total time recorded for an identical task in `Toggl`.

`Zapier` has suggested it support Asana's custom fields, however, I've been unable to see this option available.

So far I have:

1. Created a trigger when a new time entry is added in `Toggl`
2. Created a `Search` to find a task in Asana identical to the task in `Toggl`
3. Created an action to update this `Asana` task (<-- this is where I'm having issues locating the Custom Field type)

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you share maybe a screenshot of your Zap?

Comment: You can try to contact https://paulminors.com/ he is the best with Asana and Zapier

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with Zapier and Asana and [this](https://asanatraining.com/zapier-offers-introductory-support-custom-fields/) article, Zapier only allows you to set custom field values at the time of creating a new task. Unfortunately this means that you cannot update the custom fields of an already created task, they can only be set at time of creation.

If you are familiar with Python or Javascript you could use their code module to make update requests to Asana's API which is what I do when I need to update custom field data. You can read over Asana's API documentation [here](https://asana.com/developers) and more about Zapier's code module [here](https://zapier.com/help/code/) and [here](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/).